# lapply and loop - cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Tags: r

I am trying to perform a grepl function on a list of 250 dataframes each with about 50,000 single words in each cell like this:

```
df1 <- c("this","is","the","first","sentence",...)
df2 <- c("this","is","the","","sentence",...)
df3 <- c("now","the","third","sentence","appears",...)
```

I want to know how often individual words appear so I decided to put all the dataframes in a list like this:

```
df_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

and then I attempted to perform an lapply function on the list:

```
lapply(all_transcripts, function(x) x %>% filter(grepl("third", word, ignore.case=TRUE)))
```

However, each time I try to tweak that script I get the same error:

> Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
>     no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "character"

I then tried to use a loop but got the same error. The loop looked like this:

```
for (i in 1:length(all_transcripts)) {
   i %>% filter(grepl("third", word, ignore.case=TRUE))
}
```

I am not wedded to doing this in a particular way. I just want an efficient way of being able to identify how many times certain words are repeated across each the dataframes so if you have another way of doing this, I'm happy to go in a different direction. Really appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `df1` etc. are character vectors not dataframes. Can you show desired output based and your input?

Comment: I just provided those as examples. They are dataframes I constructed with this code:

for (i in 1:length(Interview_Transcripts)){
 print(i)  
 Interviews_2010 <- pdf_text(files[i]) %>% tibble(txt = .) %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, txt)}

Interviews_2010 <- data.frame(Interviews_2010)

So my desired ultimate output is just a word count for each dataframe of the number of words in each df. I designed this as an intermediate stage in which the contents of each df would be filtered so that only matching words remained (which I could then count). Thanks for your help!

Comment: how about just `unlist`ing and `table`ing the results?

Comment: Thanks for your help @user20650! How would I do that exactly?

Comment: get counts of words in all docs `tab = table(unlist(df_list))` then use this to look up counts for specific words `tab["third"]` -- but I dont know if this fits with your use case edit.. scratch that , just noticed you want it for individual dataframes

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the words to stay in each df because they represent specific time periods that I need to know about but thanks for the great suggestion. Will use it in future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is not clear the final result, these approaches could be tried:
In number one:

```
df1 <- c("this","is","the","first","sentence")
df2 <- c("this","is","the","","sentence")
df3 <- c("now","the","third","sentence","appears")
df_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)
lapply(df_list,function(x) table(x))

[[1]]
x
   first       is sentence      the     this 
       1        1        1        1        1 

[[2]]
x
               is sentence      the     this 
       1        1        1        1        1 

[[3]]
x
 appears      now sentence      the    third 
       1        1        1        1        1
```

And number two:

```
list_g <- do.call(c,df_list)
table(list_g)

list_g
          appears    first       is      now sentence      the    third     this 
       1        1        1        2        1        3        3        1        2
```

Hoping this can help.

Comment: The first one is the answer I need. Thank you!